# What is a better Javascript practice for outputting content into multiple HTML divs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on a script that would output a loading image to specific divs if a file has been uploaded. The script works.

I was wondering if there is a **better practice** for this? At the moment I am just copying the same output line but replacing the div ID.

Javascript:

```
if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    $('#pred1').html('<img src="' + loader + '" class="loading" />');
    $('#pred2').html('<img src="' + loader + '" class="loading" />');
    $('#pred3').html('<img src="' + loader + '" class="loading" />');
    $('#pred4').html('<img src="' + loader + '" class="loading" />');
    $('#pred5').html('<img src="' + loader + '" class="loading" />');
  } else { alert("No file selcted!"); }
}
```

HTML:

```
</div>
  <a href="#pred1">1</a>
  <a href="#pred2">2</a>
  <a href="#pred3">3</a>
  <a href="#pred4">4</a>
  <a href="#pred5">5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a shared class: `$('.pred').html('<img src="' + loader + '" class="loading" />');`. Don't forget to add the class to the `a` elements that you are targeting

Comment: Pro-tip: questions hinging on "better" or "best" rarely do well here..

Comment: It depends on limitations and environment (and opinion).  If you ***have*** to write HTML in JS, your options are the DOM API which includes HTMLFragments, innerHTML and a bunch of other mechanisms or some framework like React, Angular, Dojo, etc.  Favor whatever is **readable**.  String concatenation is hard to read.

Comment: If you add a class to the surrounding div, you can use something like `$('.images a').html(...);` and it will run for all matching elements.

Comment: Thank you for the shared class suggestion, I didn't even think to do that. @JaredSmith maybe so but I don't know how else I can learn good practice so I don't one day send spaghetti code to my work colleagues lol.

Comment: @CezaraH that's a great instinct you have, and I encourage you to follow it by reading good code (open source stuff from top tech companies or their employees is a good place to start). But there's a problem: there isn't necessarily One and Only True Path that everyone agrees on for a given issue (there are however *infinite ways* to screw it up). So questions like that tend to generate a lot of "tabs vs spaces" style arguments that don't go anywhere, which is why we tend not to allow them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Your element in HTML Like bellow:

```
</div>
  <a class="" href="#pred1">1</a>
  <a class="you-desired-class" href="#pred2">2</a>
  <a class="you-desired-class" href="#pred3">3</a>
  <a class="you-desired-class" href="#pred4">4</a>
  <a class="you-desired-class" href="#pred5">5</a>
</div>
```

Then Change your JS like bellow:

```
if (file) {
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  $('.you-desired-class').html('<img src="' + reader.result + '" class="loading" />');
} else {
  alert("No file selcted!"); 
}
```

Comment: BTW, instead of saying _"change your code to this"_, you could explain what your code does, which is in this case using a common class instead of IDs. That will make the answer a lot better especially if OP and other users can't see the change

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did not realise I can use a shared class.

Comment: Related to above comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks for the suggestion.  I will definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('[id^=pred').html('<img src="' + loader + '" class="loading" />');
```

Comment: @downvoter, if you don't like the question downvote the question not the answer. They each have their own up/down vote buttons for a reason

Comment: Simple and effective, thank you for your help.

Comment: @CezaraH, you are most welcome:)

Comment: This is not a jQuery Selector, it's a valid CSS selector. jQuery simply supports all valid CSS selectors.